# Vue - wrap HTML5 element

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I want to create a component that wraps a `textarea` element. Its function is to add custom functionality and custom styling, but I don't want it to be scoped in its own scope - rather, the parent should be able bind to regular events like `input`.

Example of what is needed, but will not work (problem is highlighted in `parent.vue`):

### `area.vue:`

```
<template>
    <textarea rows="1"></textarea>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        mounted() {
            // do something...
        }
    }
</script>

<style scoped>
    textarea {
        height: 100%;
    }
</style>
```

### `parent.vue:`

```
<template>
    <area @input="doSomething"></area>
</template>

<script>
    import Area from "./area.vue"

    export default {
        methods: {
            doSomething(){
                // NOT TRIGGERED!
                // `input` event is not passed over to parent scope
            }
        },
        components: {
            Area
        }
    }
</script>
```

I do not want to explicitly write in `this.$emit` calls into the component.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You only need to add [`.native`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#v-on) to `@input`.

Vue's `v-on`/`@`, when used on a component (without `.native`), only listens to custom events declared by `emit`.

Answer (score 2):

you can pass methods from the parent to the child as props, i.e.

**parent**

```
<area :do-something="doSomething"></area>
```

**child**

```
# template
<textarea rows="1" @input="doSomething"></textarea>

# script
export default {
  props: ['doSomething'],
  ...
```

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately you can't do this, but you can cheat and get pretty close.

```
mounted() {
    var self = this;
    Object.keys(Event.prototype).forEach(function(ev) {
       self.$refs.text.addEventListener(ev.toLowerCase(), function(d) {
           self.$emit(ev.toLowerCase(), d);
           console.log("emitting", ev, d);
       })
   })
}
```

With this you get access to `mousedown`, `mouseup`, `mouseover`, `mouseout`, `mousemove`, `mousedrag`, `click`, `dblclick`, `keydown`, `keyup`, `keypress`, `dragdrop`, `focus`, `blur`, `select` and `change` events. Then in your parent template...

```
<my-textarea @keyup="update()" @change="somethingElse()"></my-textarea>
```

Here's the fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/rdjjpc7a/371/